# CSS selector: Style the first "a" inside a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble finding the correct CSS selector, the structure I have looks like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I would like to style the `a` element of the first `div`

I have tried with this selector but with no luck

```
div:first-child a{}
```

Comment: It's working perfect, if the only html code on the page is that you specified. Plaease, show the full page.

Answer (score 2):

`first-child` should work absolutely well, you can try

```
div:nth-of-type(1) a { /* Or div:first-child a */
    color: red;
}
```

The above selector will select all 1st `div` element and will apply color to all `a` which are inside 1st `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub6Xp/)

If you are willing to style 1st occurrence of `a` in every `div` tag than you need to use

```
div a:nth-of-type(1) { /* Or div a:first-child */
    color: red;
}
```

Here every 1st `a` will be selected in every `div` tag

Last but not the least if you want to select 1st `a` only in 1st `div` than use the below selector

```
div:nth-of-type(1) a:nth-of-type(1) { /* Or div:first-child a:first-child */
    color: red;
}
```

> Note: If still the above selectors doesn't work, than the possibility
>   is either some rule is more specific than the rules you are declaring,
>   or `!important` is used somewhere, or (least chances) you are testing
>   on older browsers

Answer (score 0):

Your own example is working too.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Pea3/

```
div:first-child a {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first div will be selected and all `a` recive the color `#CCC`. I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
div:first-child a { 
    color: #CCC;
}
```

Else test this solution, that selects the first div and styles the first a tag in the div:

```
div:first-child a:first-child(1) {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

Else you have problems with the `:first-child` selector use the `:nth-of-type({ number expression | odd | even })` selector.